# Error occured while starting App. Original error: com.abc.xyz.ui.SplashActivity or com.abc.xyz.dev.com.abc.xyz.ui.SplashActivity never started

Tags: appium

I recently started facing this issue.

I upgraded my appium version to 1.6.5 but while running automation when i try to launch app i am getting following error.

```
[ADB] Error: com.abc.xyz.ui.SplashActivity or com.abc.xyz.dev.com.abc.xyz.ui.SplashActivity never started
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (../../../lib/tools/apk-utils.js:153:7)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Making error more readable

Answer (score 0):

Appium couldn't automatically match the activity when your android app been launched.
This can be solved by providing activity and package name you want appium to wait for in [capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md):
E.g

```
"appWaitActivity" : "com.abc.xyz.ui.SomeActivity",
"appWaitPackage" : "com.abc.xyz"
```

You can use `adb shell dumpsys activity` to get current activity of your app

Comment: Both package and activity are provided in capabilities already. The same code was running fine a couple of days ago. I upgraded appium to 1.6.5 and i am facing this issue

Comment: How about start using appium 1.7.2? You didn't give much context (list of capabilities, your appium client version, full server log) so how do you expect people will understand your issue?